# splinter nested <html> documents

Tags: html, python-3.x, browser-automation, splinter

I am working on some website automation. Currently, I am unable to access a nested html documents with Splinter. Here's a sample website that will help demonstrate what I am dealing with: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_elem_select

I am trying to get into the select element and choose the "saab" option. I am stuck on how to enter the second html document. I've read the documentation and saw nothing. I'm hoping there is a way with Python.

Any thoughts?

**Before Solution:**

```
from splinter import Browser

exe = {"executable_path": "chromedriver.exe"}
browser = Browser("chrome",**exe, headless=False)

url = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_elem_select"
browser.visit(url)

# This is where I'm stuck. I cannot find a way to access the second (nested) html doc
innerframe = browser.find_by_name("iframeResult").first
innerframe.find_by_name("cars")[0]
```

**Solution:**

```
from splinter import Browser

exe = {"executable_path": "chromedriver.exe"}
browser = Browser("chrome",**exe, headless=False)

url = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_elem_select"
browser.visit(url)

with browser.get_iframe("iframeResult") as iframe:
    cars = iframe.find_by_name("cars")
    cars.select("saab")
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that these are called [iframes](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/IFrame-Inline-Frame/). Once I learned the terminology, it wasn't too hard to figure out how it interact with it. *"Nested html documents"* was not returning the results I needed to find the solution.

I hope this helps someone out in the future!

Comment: @Alex Will do. What I found is that after reaching the website, you need to create a with statement block to work within the iframe. It's relatively easy once I found the correct terminology.